# Regex to match ASCII Table character with decimal value

Tags: regex, decimal, ascii

So I need a **Regex** to match the **ASCII** character **STX**(Start Of Text) which is number 2 on ASCII Table.
I tried `^` as [Regex101.com](http://Regex101.com) suggest for start of text but it was unsuccessful.

Then I tried `[[:ascii:]]` which was matching for all ASCII characters.
Is there any way to match a specific ASCII character using Regex? eg:`[ASCII(2)]`. I know I can do that with `PHP`/`Java` etc but I have to do it with Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match ASCII number codes by using `\x` to match escaped hexadecimal codes, e.g:

`\x02` should match STX